# Replace commas with point while input numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

now i'm working with HTML5-Javascript and i have this code to automatically add separators in my input number :

```
<input class="number">
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2C95Z/)

it will add commas ( , ) if have more than 3 numbers, and now i want to change the commas ( , ) with point ( . ), like this :

input: 10000

output: 10.000

how to do that?

Comment: The code you provided supports `,` as the thousand separator AND `.` as the decimal point. Should the decimal point become `,`? Or are you expecting integers exclusively?

Comment: i want to replace `,` with `.` , replacing 1,000 with 1.000

Comment: @husin.anti  so if number is 1,000.000 how would new number lookalike then ?

Comment: Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deepak_vatts/nn2ndeLw/) . I have removed the decimal number check. Now number would only contain '.' This is not a good idea to remove the decimal check but it seems all you need here.

Comment: It's works now, thanks :). yeah i think so, but now i want to change USD to IDR, IDR using ",".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery focusout event to format the numbers ,Below code will replace all **,** with **.** when the focus out from the text box.

```
$('input.number').on("focusout",function (event) {
   $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/,/g,'.'));
});
```

Comment: @husin.anti you want to remove all "," with "." right ?

Comment: yeah, i want to use "." , i tried your code but it didn't work for me, or you can include your demo in jsfiddle

Comment: @husin.anti FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/aruncm/2C95Z/49/ , this will replace all " , " with " . " . Please check and let me know whether it worked or not :)

Answer (score 1):

### JQuery

```
$("input.number").on("input", function() {
   $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/,/g, "."));
});

$("input.number").on("change", function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/,/g, "."));
});
```

### Javascript

```
document.querySelector("input.number").addEventListener("input", function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/,/g, ".");
}, false);

document.querySelector("input.number").addEventListener("change", function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/,/g, ".");
}, false);
```

### Events

[input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event

[change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event